# Installing "ipoptr" package in R

Tags: r, installation, interface, package

I have a problem with installing the package "ipoptr" in R. When I try to install it, R gives me this error:

```
A version of this package for your version of R might be available elsewhere,
see the ideas at
https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-patched/R-admin.html#Installing-packages
```

I tried it for both R-4.1.3 and R-3.63, but I got the same error.
I would appreciate it if anyone could help me.

Thanks

Comment: This is because it is not longer available on CRAN, and it looks like it hasn't been maintained in 10 years judging by its GH repo: https://github.com/jyypma/ipoptr

Comment: How can I find this package for R?

Comment: I don't believe it can.

Comment: This Q&A may potentially help you https://github.com/jyypma/ipoptr/issues/3